# Where am I going wrong with revalidatePath

Tags: next.js, vercel

I know, a lot of people have already asked for it, but I can't find a reason why this code doesn't work!

I'm using NextJs 14, Prisma and the action servers. To sum up: if I use revalidatePath in the updateOpenings function, it should delete the cache in "/" and the next time you visit the page you should see the new data.

But this is not the case on Vercel. It works great on localhost, but not in production. I solved it by adding also revalidatePath() in the getOpenings function and in this way everything works normally, but it should be superfluous and especially in this way instead of having the data cached on the homepage, there is a request for data from the database at every visit. Where is the mistake?

action.js:

```
"use server";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismaClient";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export const getOpenings = async () => {
    const getOpeningsResult = await prisma.opening.findMany({
      select: {
       day : true,
       lunchStart : true,
       lunchEnd : true,
       dinnerStart : true,
       dinnerEnd : true,
       closed : true,
      },
      orderBy: {day:"asc"}
    });
    revalidatePath("/");
    return getOpeningsResult;
};


export const updateOpenings = async (formdata) => {
  const day = formdata.get("day");
  const lunchStart = formdata.get("lunchStart");
  const lunchEnd = formdata.get("lunchEnd");
  const dinnerStart = formdata.get("dinnerStart");
  const dinnerEnd = formdata.get("dinnerEnd");
  const closed = formdata.get("closed")==="on";


    const existingDay = await prisma.opening.findUnique({
      where: {
        day: day,
      },
    });

    if (!existingDay) {
      await prisma.Opening.create({
        data: {
          day: day,
          lunchStart: lunchStart,
          lunchEnd: lunchEnd,
          dinnerStart: dinnerStart,
          dinnerEnd: dinnerEnd,
          closed: closed,
        },
      });
      return { success: true, message: "Orario creato con successo" };
    }

    if (existingDay) {
      await prisma.Opening.update({
        where: {
          day: day,
        },
        data: {
          day: day,
          lunchStart: lunchStart,
          lunchEnd: lunchEnd,
          dinnerStart: dinnerStart,
          dinnerEnd: dinnerEnd,
          closed: closed,
        },
      });
      return { success: true, message: "Orario aggiornato con successo" };
    }
    
    revalidatePath("/");

};
```

and app/page.jsx

```
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import Slider from "./components/Slider";

import { getOpenings } from "@/app/actions/openingForms";

const Home = async () => {
  const openings = await getOpenings();

  return (
    <div className={`container boxShadow ${styles.main}`}>
      //rest of code

      <article id="orari" className={styles.orari_wrapper}>
        {openings.map((opening) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={opening.day}
              className={styles.orari__container}>
              <h4 className={styles.orari__giorno}>{opening.day.slice(3)}</h4>
              <div className={styles.orari__fasce}>
                {opening && !opening.closed ? (
                  <div className={styles.aperto}>
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <h5>Pranzo:</h5>
                        <span>dalle:&nbsp;{opening.lunchStart}</span>
                        <span>&nbsp;alle:&nbsp;{opening.lunchEnd}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <h5>Cena:</h5>
                        <span>dalle:&nbsp;{opening.dinnerStart}</span>
                        <span>&nbsp;alle:&nbsp;{opening.dinnerEnd}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div className={styles.chiusura}>Chiuso</div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </article>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```